# how to ignore source code ts check which in node_modules compiled by typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, tsc

code struct like this:

// instance code

node_modules/source_code/index.ts

// my truly code

import { xxx } from 'source_code';

// Webpack config maybe like that:

test('.ts | .tsx').include('source_code');

// ts error

// ERROR in node_modules xxx

how to solve it, ignore node_modules ts complie?

Comment: I can't quite understand what you are asking. Can you try to clarify? Perhaps it would help if you provided a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below to exclude node_modules

Add an empty "types" option in "compilerOptions":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: crying，it doesn't work

Comment: Hey, I have updated my compiler option with skipLibCheck to true can you try it again?

Comment: no，because it was ts file not .d.ts file，the node_modules package not be complied，skipLibCheck doesn't work